# problem changing domain name to Ruby application

Tags: ruby, dns, routes

I changed the domain name for my ruby application but when I run it I get

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

In the log file it says

> Routing error no route matches [GET] "/"

In my routing file `config/routes.rb` I changed domaincontraint to domain new.
I must say that this configuration worked with my old domain name.

Am I missing some place to change the domain name? Please note I am very noobie to ruby

Answer (score 0):

So, the good news is you are getting `Routing error no route matches [GET] "/"`. this means your request reaches the rails application. Because in most cases it doesn't even come pass your server such as `Nginx`. In such cases its nothing to do with rails.

However, since you get the above routing error, that means your request hits the rails app.

Few things to check here:

1) make sure you have a `root` url defined in your `config/routes` file.
2) Make sure you url you are trying to access has a matching route.

For an example, say if you do `http://<your domain>/products`

Then in the routes, you should have `products GET /products(.:format) products#index`

You can check this by running `rake routes` from root of your rails app.

Also, it will be helpful for you to update the question with your `config/routes` file and also the url you are trying to access.